# dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: produces different results in iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I have a UIViewController which I'll call root, which is presenting (via modal segue) another UIViewController (firstChild), which is presenting (again via modal segue) a UINavigationController (topChild).  In top child I do the following:

```
[root dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    [root performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToNewFirstChild" sender:self];
}];
```

In iOS 7, the effect of this is that topChild remains on the screen until the segue to newFirstChild has been completed, and newFirstChild is then displayed (presented by root).  I like that.

In iOS 8, the effect is that topChild is immediately removed from the screen, firstChild briefly is displayed and then removed, leaving root to be displayed until the segue has been completed, and newFirstChild is then displayed (presented by root).  I don't like that.

If I choose to animate the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`, the following results happen:  In iOS 7, topChild is dismissed with animation, without ever revealing firstChild (as advertised in the documentation), leaving root to be displayed until the segue has been completed; and in iOS8, topChild is immediately removed from the screen, leaving firstChild, which is dismissed with animation (contrary to the documentation!), again leaving root to be displayed until the segue has been completed.

Any idea how I can get the effect produced in iOS 7 (either with or without animation) in iOS 8?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble you're dealing with here is that you're trying to call a method in the completion block of `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` of a View Controller that you're dismissing (and thus deallocating), thus the sporadic and unpredictable behaviour.

I'd recommend using something like `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification when the view controller is being dismissed, and retain a handler in your parent (root) controller that can receive the notification.

In your root view controller, call this somewhere (maybe in `prepareForSegue`?):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(topChildWasDismissed:)
                                                 name:@"TopChildDismissed"
                                               object:nil];
```

You'll also need a handler method in your root VC:

```
- (void)topChildWasDismissed {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToNewFirstChild" sender:self];
}
```

Then in your top child:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TopChildDismissed" object:self];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks--I'll try sending a notification and see if that improves things.  But note that dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: does not dismiss the receiver; it dismisses the receiver's child UIViewController--from the documentation "Dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the receiver", and "If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack."